# TreeView - Saving changes to a database table

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a C# winforms app form with a `TreeView` on it. Populating the `TreeView` is done using a stored proc and view (not table) from database.

This works fine as it puts the information into the `TreeView` as all root nodes. I have drag and drop available to the users for the `TreeView` so they can move nodes and have a `parent/child/grandchild/`etc. However, many are needed. This also works fine.

What I am struggling with (more like getting frustrated with) is saving the users' `TreeView` changes back to the database table. I considered making the change with each move but decided to use a button click event when all is done being moved.

I am providing what code I have so far. Just remember that this is not final look of the click event since button is not named plus a few other cleanups needed as well and the `sqlUpdate` will actually become a stored proc.

In the `sqlUpdate` there are 2 parameters listed; `@parentid` and `@industryid`.  If I was to hard code those with a number (ex: 1 and 4) the update works and makes the changes in the table to the correct industry id.  When the `TreeView` is populated it uses three (3) fields from the table; `IndustryID`, `ParentID`, `IndustryItem`.  These go into a datatable and to the `TreeView`.

What I am getting frustrated over is getting the `@parentid` and `@industryid` which is why I am posting here for help. I've done updates, deletes, inserts many times but for some reason this is making draw a blank.

I do realize I need to specify the parameters in the code but I'm thinking that is where the issue is.  Here are the 2 lines;

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentid", ?????);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@industryid", ?????);
```

And here is the click handler:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        {
            string sqlUpdate = "UPDATE tblIndustry SET IndustryItemParentID = @parentid WHERE IndustryID = @industryid";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.Connection = conn;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = sqlUpdate;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is an error." + '\r' + '\n' + '\r' + '\n' + ex.ToString(), "NOTICE", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

For @industryid, use an auto-incremented id column in the database. Assign that value to the treeview node tags when you populate the treeview. Then use the value of treeview.parent.tag for @parentid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Do you have an example?  Here is the code for populating the treeview.

Comment: Never mind on responding.  I have changed as to the way the info is being displayed.  Spent way too much time on this already.